# Problem with Laravel and timestamp utc on different field

Tags: json, api, laravel-10

In the dabase i store the validation_parcellaire_at with :

```
$data = ['validation_parcellaire' => ($validation==1?\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString():null)];
```

In the database structure :
[image]

The result is :

[image]

[image]

The other field have the same info for the update :
[image]

When i retrieve the data with my software i get this :

[image]

And to retrieve in Laravel, i call the route which call :

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

     return $this->sendResponse(new UserResource($user), 'Utilisateur trouvé.');
```

Do you have any idea of what can happend to have the same data in the database and not the same result in the json with the API ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week-end i found the solution, in the model of the table we need to cast the variable's type like that :

```
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'validation_parcellaire_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Regards